SHA-3 hash function standard references
I have noticed a slight change in the standard documentation of FIPS-202 and ISO/IEC 10118-3 documents for algorithm 5:rc(t) as below:
ISO/IEC 10118-3
Algorithm 5: rc(t)
Input: integer t
Output: bit rc(t)
Steps:
a)If t mod 255 = 0, return 1.
c)For i from 1 to t mod 255, let:
b) Let R = 10 000 000.
1) R = 0 || R;
2) R[0] = R[0] ⊕ R[8];
3) R[6] = R[6] ⊕ R[8];
4) R[3] = R[3] ⊕ R[8];
5) R[2] = R[2] ⊕ R[8];
6) R = Trunc8

FIPS-202
Algorithm 5: rc(t)
Input:
integer t.
Output:
bit rc(t).
Steps:
1. If t mod 255 = 0, return 1.
2. Let R = 10000000.
3. For i from 1 to t mod 255, let:
a. R = 0 || R;
b. R[0] = R[0] ⊕ R[8];
c. R[4] = R[4] ⊕ R[8];
d. R[5] = R[5] ⊕ R[8];
e. R[6] = R[6] ⊕ R[8];
f. R =Trunc8[R].
4. Return R[0]

Can anybody explain these difference or are the same?

ISO/IEC 10118-3 is usually paywalled..

Is the ISO/IEC 10118-3 pseudocode from the published standard ISO/IEC 10118-3:2018 (october 2018), from some FDIS or CD, or from some other source?

I've voted to close this since without all of the pseudo-code and definitions from ISO/IEC 10118-3, this question is not answerable at all!

The aim of ISO/IEC 10118-3:2018 (partial preview) sections 19 to 22, and appendixes B.14 to B.17, is (I believe) to match the algorithm, results, and test vectors of FIPS 202. Any discrepancy there may be in ISO/IEC 10118-3 w.r.t. FIPS 202 that would change the output is probably unintentional and should be ignored IMHO.
Update: As pointed in comment, even if in the ISO/IEC 10118-3 pseudocode of the question we reorder b) and c), ignore conventions for numbering, and assume the result is implicit, the two algorithms are NOT equivalent due to differences in indexes. I initially missed that.
I can't believe such discrepancy is intentional. I don't have a copy of ISO/IEC 10118-3:2018 to check (this is the fourth and current version, and the only one with SHA3).

The two algorithms are not the same: the ISO document twiddles different bits ({6,3,2} vs {4,5,6}). This can't be explained by different a endianness convention (it would be {4,3,2}). It could be explained by attempting an endianness flip but accidentally keeping one of the original positions. I don't have the ISO document so I don't know whether it uses the same notations and I don't know if the question quotes it correctly.

so that design of SHA3 for ISO/IEC and NIST standards are the same right?

SHA3 is SHA3. The ultimate source is NIST and their test vectors.

One of my observation: I have implemented using NIST FIPS-202. For testing purpose I used NIST test vectors and other vectors that uses ISO/IEC 10118-3 and I found that both vectors works fine with what i have implemented but upto certiian length like msg_len = 60552 and beyond not giving expected result for ISO/IEC implemented test vectors.

Ignore ISO. Not just for this but in general. Their whole approach is ridiculous. It's way too behind closed doors. Security standards should not be paywalled. They have also made careless mistakes in the past.

@samuel-lucas6: NIST and other US agencies are not exemplary either. They consistently attempt to standardize or otherwise sneak breakable crypto: 56-bit key in DES, Dual_EC_DRBG (reportedly made default in BSAFE for $10M), PBKDF2 still deemed acceptable for password hashing, and more. OTOH they tend to make less silly mistakes and err on the side of caution.

@fgrieu I completely agree and shouldn't have left that out of my comment. I'm also not a fan of how NIST writes documents. Everybody complains about implementation mistakes and yet specifications are needlessly difficult to read.

@samuel-lucas6 Biham and Shamir showed a 2^37 time differential attack on DES in 1991 requiring 2^47 chosen plaintexts. NSA knew about differential cryptanalysis and applied it to the design of DES. So calling 56-bit key DES a "weakening" seems at least as incorrect as saying that the 64-bit key DES has 64 bits of security.
I like the theory that they "right-sized" the key length to make it better reflect the effective security.

@MarshRay: if that's serious: what supporting evidence is there about that "right-sized" theory? What about the account, from a book internally published by the NSA (declassified after many FOIA requests), which is clear that the key size was chosen to make the algorithm breakable? Also, in practice, 2^47 chosen plaintexts (1 petabyte) was unrealistic, and remains impractical.

@fgrieu Interesting document. If you believe it reflects reality, note that it says "NSA worked closely with IBM to strengthen the algorithm against all except brute force attacks and to strengthen [the] S-boxes."
When brute force is the best attack, the primitive is secure. It is literally the opposite of a backdoor.
Even back in 1976, a brute force DES cracking machine was straightforward engineering from off-the-shelf parts.
Extension of DES to longer keys (e.g. 112 bit 3DES) was straightforward too.
So what attacker advantage could they have possibly expected to gain?

@MarshRay: Yes I trust that the NSA and IBM collaborated to strengthen the S-boxes to some degree. At least, the NSA confirmed to IBM that their efforts to select good S-boxes where sound, if only by asking that the S-box rationale remains unpublished, for fear that differential cryptanalysis (that the NSA and IBM knew) became public too soon. That's well corroborated. As to what the NSA gained with a small key: they could break single-DES, and that long was in wide use, and 3DES prohibited for freely exportable crypto. Other WW2 allies similarly limited key size for civilian crypto.

To me the simplest explanation for the observed behavior is that NSA behaved like a large, bureaucratic, government agency, with heavily compartmentalized pockets of competence. So we might assume that those who know don't talk, and those who talk (i.e., interact with Congress and NBS/NIST) don't know. What we do know is that whoever was actually involved in the design produced a primitive still secure today, while the 'talkers' were let loose to confuse and misdirect. Maybe a little public distrust in DES was intentionally used to slow its adoption by adversaries. A real psyop, if you will.
